# Не работает url.Parse

Tags: golang

Простой код:

```
_, err := url.Parse("555")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Но не уходит на ошибку, почему?

Может я не правильно понимаю работу `url.Parse` - я думал что если передаваемое значение не `url` - то в `err` - должна быть какая-то ошибка...

Comment: Что значит "Не уходит на ошибку"? Если код выдает ошибку, приведите её текст. Если он должен выдавать ошибку, но не выдает, укажите, какую ошибку он должен вывести и почему.

Comment: Может я не правильно понимаю работу url.Parse - я думал что если передаваемое значение не url - то в err - должна быть какая-то ошибка... нет?

Comment: Вставьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Ну вообще-то `555` является вполне валидным URL, просто в нём отсутствуют все компоненты кроме `Path`

Comment: Получается невалидным является только явно int или есть еще варианты?

А как проверить url - что он является явным url типа http://mail.ru

Comment: Правила построения урла можно найти тут https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, я учусь и пока не способен понять этот ответ(

Comment: Но в целом я понял что я не правильно понимаю работу url.Parse - нужно удалить вопрос или как его тут закрыть как решенный?

Comment: Да оставьте, зачем удалять. Ничего плохого в нем нет.

Comment: Что такое "явный url"?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял - что нужно более точно формулировать вопрос.
К сожалению я не смогу ответить что такое явный url - для меня это понятие примерно такое - если я в строку браузера введу 555 - то браузер не посчитает это url и отправит в гугл, а например mail.ru или localhost - посчитает и попробует по нему перейти.

Comment: @andreymal вы мне подсказали способ, я понял что нужно проверять url.Hostname - и это мою проблему решает.

Comment: В такой формулировке задача немножечко сложнее: если вы введёте `mail.rus`, то браузер тоже отправит в гугл, но чем он принципиально хуже чем тот же `mail.ru` какой-нибудь?)

Comment: Отличается тем, что доменной зоны rus нет - значит не валидный url... в чем диссонанс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несмотря на свое имя, тип URL в go представляет собой не URL (в соотв. с rfc1738), а URI reference (в соотв. с rfc3986). По сути, там допустимо присутствие только пути `Path`, а для URL требуется еще, как минимум, схема `Scheme` и чтобы хост `Host` и путь `Path` формировали schemepart.

Метод `url.Parse` выполняет не разбор URL, а разрешение потенциально относительного URI в контексте потенциально пустого базового URI (обертка для `ResolveReference` с пустым базовым URI). Так как URL являются подмножеством URI, то этот метод вполне может использоваться и для разбора URL.
Например:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main(){
    // только относительный путь, а не URL
    res, err := url.Parse("/../555")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
    // полноценный URL, включет схему и путь
    base, err := url.Parse("http://example.com/directory/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // вызов напрямую с непустым базовым URI
    // "/directory/" схлопывается с "/../"
    fmt.Println(base.ResolveReference(res))
}
```

> /../555
> http://example.com/555

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:go,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27package+main%0Aimport+(%0A%09%22fmt%22%0A%09%22net/url%22%0A)%0A%0Afunc+main()%7B%0A%09res,+err+:%3D+url.Parse(%22/../555%22)%0A%09if+err+!!%3D+nil+%7B%0A%09%09panic(err)%0A%09%7D%0A%09fmt.Println(res)%0A%09base,+err+:%3D+url.Parse(%22http://example.com/directory/%22)%0A%09if+err+!!%3D+nil+%7B%0A%09%09panic(err)%0A%09%7D%0A%09fmt.Println(base.ResolveReference(res))%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Go+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gl1210,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:go,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gc+1.21+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gc+1.21%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gc+1.21+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

`mail.rus` и `mail.ru` - это вообще доменные имена, валидность которых браузер проверяет выполняя запрос по протоколу DNS

Comment: Не по DNS, какой-нибудь `maiiil.ru` не существует, но браузер всё равно пытается его открыть

Comment: За полный ответ спасибо, меня скорее валидация url интересовала - но стало понятнее как работает url.Parse

Comment: @andreymal Чтобы открыть, надо определить, по какому IP адресу делать запрос, а для этого делается запрос DNS.

Comment: @user7860670 и при неудаче этого запроса  браузер не станет открывать гугл как в случае с `mail.rus` а просто выдаст ошибку

Comment: @andreymal Что именно потом покажет браузер - это скорее от браузера и его настроек зависит.

Answer (score 0):

Частый случай решения моей проблемы, это проверять Hostname, примерно так:

```
u, err := url.Parse("555")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else if u.Hostname() == "" {
    fmt.Println("url не содержит Hostname")
}
```